# how to test my 2.1 android application on 2.2 device?

Tags: android

i have made an android application using android 2.1. i want to test how my application will behave on a device with android 2.2 and 2.3. How do i test it in eclipse. i do not have any real devices to test my application. 
In eclipse, if i make an emulator with 2.2 , it does not list up in my application run configration. what i mean to say is that eclipse is not allowing me to run my 2.1 app on 2.2 device. how do i test my application on an emulator?

thank you in advance.

Comment: Maybe you have set  `android:maxSdkVersion="7" ` in your manifest?

Answer (score 0):

Launch the emulator in which you have to test the application. Wait until the home screen is ready.

then run the application it will load it in the emulator currently running.

You have specify the following line in emulator,

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to run your application on any device (emulator or physical) that has a version greater than the one specified in your manifest minSdkVersion attribute.

Note that you can also run an application compiled with a greater SDK version on an older emulator (again, the minSdkVersion attribute should be having a proper value). This way you can test support for the newest features without crashing on the older platforms.

Answer (score 0):

The previous answers are both good. To be more specific, start your 2.2 emulator by going in "Window" -> "Android SDK and AVD manager", select the emulator you want to test on and press Start.

After the emulator finished loading run your project with "Run Configurations...", select "Manual" deployment in the "Target" tab and after you press Run you should be able to select the emulator from a list of running Android devices.

Hope this is clear enough.